# using framework and simple.php page want to remove .php from simple page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a CodeIgniter installation and a separate `simple.php` file which is outside of the framework directory. I want to remove the `.php` extension from the `simple` page.

Currently, I'm using this code which removes `index.php` from CodeIgniter requests, but it's not working outside of the framework:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

How can I remove the `.php` extension?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that you have a CodeIgniter installation in, for example,  `/foo/bar/my-ci-app` which has a `.htaccess` file in it.

You also have a `simple.php` residing in `/foo/bar/simple.php` (outside of the framework). And now you want to remove the `.php` extension from that `simple.php` file, right?

Directives defined in an [htaccess file](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) are only effective upon their residing directory and its sub-directories. Since your `simple.php` file is outside of CodeIgniter installation, that htaccess file is no use for you as its directives do not take effect backward.

You need another htaccess file residing beside your `simple.php` file in `foo/bar/.htaccess`. The rewrite rule you need to drop the php extension is as follows:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # Just to be sure that these rules has no conflict with your
    # codeigniter rewrite rules, we're gonna discard the following
    # rewrite rule if the request uri contains its directory name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !my-ci-app

    # If the corresponding php file exists
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

    # And the request uri does not contain a php file format,
    # for example, whatever.php, rewrite the request to a file
    # named as %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (simple in your case) and add
    # a .php extension to it.
    RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
## Results
# simple  => simple.php
# example => example.php
```